# How to get Encoding in xml file using libXML?

Tags: ios, xml, xml-parsing, libxml2

I am using libxml to parse xml response. I found out that libxml detects encoding by reading xml file header. But I could not find how to get that detected encoding.I did the following to get libxml to detect encoding:

```
xmlCreatePushParserCtxt(&simpleSAXHandlerStruct, (__bridge void *)(self), [data bytes], [data length], NULL);
```

I came across

```
xmlDetectCharEncoding(const unsigned char * in, int len)
```

which returns the detected encoding but that is not from first line of xml file.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After parsing a document, you can find the encoding in the `encoding` slot of the [`xmlDoc` struct](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlDoc).

**EDIT:** If you use a push parser with your own SAX handler, no `xmlDoc` will be built. In this case, you can get the encoding from an `xmlParserCtxtPtr` via `ctxt->encoding` (or maybe `ctxt->input->encoding`) but only after the XML declaration has been parsed. This means that you have to call `xmlParseChunk` at least once and make sure that enough data has been fed to the push parser.

Comment: Thanks for the Response!! You pointed me to right direction. I tried the myDoc property of xmlParserCtxtPtr structure. but it gives me null. There is "encoding" property of xmlParserCtxtPtr struct also. Is that the same as the one you are referring to?

Comment: Thanks nwellnhof !!! I did that and I am sure first chunk will definitely get xml header when loading data asynchronously...